# How to Extend Laravel Verification

Tags: laravel

I am working on a Laravel App which uses Laravel Verification.

I have set up a Laravel Verification.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('role')->default('family');
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->date('trialExpires')->nullable();
        $table->string('avatar')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('sub_paid_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('session_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('password')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

I am trying to update the `trialExpires` column when the user verifies his email.

I would have done this

```
$user = User::find(Auth::id());
// get the current time
$current = Carbon::now();
// add 30 days to the current time
$user->trialExpires = $current->addDays(30);
$user->save();
```

I don't know how to implement this function when the user verifies his email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can listen to the event

```php
/**
 * The event listener mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogVerifiedUser',
    ],
]
```

Once it has been verified (check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/verification) on how to add the verification process to the model etc.) you can add the expiration value to your column.

Comment: This is a good start, but adding a bit of detail, including [documentation links](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/events#defining-listeners), on how to write an event listener (or even mentioning that it's necessary) would be helpful.